# What does it mean to assign something as false or true?

Tags: javascript

```
var girl = { 
arm : true, 
brain : false, 
ears : true 
};
```

What does this mean?

Comment: It's the code representation of a girl with an arm and ears, but without a brain.

Comment: I know that girl!

Comment: @Vincent - you not alone - I know her too

Comment: It means that the variable (or in this case the properties) contains a boolean value. Not sure what you want to know here. What it **means** depends on the application. `var answer = 42;` might not mean much to you, but it means much to me ;)

Comment: I wonder if that was a troll attempt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creates an object with the name girl. The object has three properties (arm, brain, ears) which are set to different values. In this case to either `true` or `false`, which are [Boolean values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).

Answer (score 2):

This is creating a JavaScript object in the variable `girl` which contains three boolean values named `arm`, `brain` and `ears` which are set to the values `true`, `false` and `true` respectively.